# how to get every instance of a word( i.e alphanumeric) from a string and change it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string such as:

```
{
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to change **props** into **"props"** and **option** into **"option"** and similarly every word which this whole string might have.

I am doing this because in the original format JSON.parse() is throwing error as this is not in JSON string which should look like this:

```
{
    "props": {
        "options": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any suggestion don't hesitate to share. Thank you.

Comment: what a strange string... anyway - try `str.replace(/([a-z]+)/ig, "'$1'")` - it won't cover any special characters in object keys

Comment: This has nothing to do with vue

Comment: Do you have access to the object before being treated as a string? Because if you do, you can `JSON.stringify(myObject)` and it will create a valid json string

Comment: @Roomy thank you  man . Worked like a butter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match all occurrences and replace them:

```
var str = `{
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array
        }
    }
}`;
var jsonString = str.replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"');
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: @GauravKumar This answer is incorrect, the regex would not match only the keys, it would also match any values too.

Comment: @Acidic if you don't match the values, you won't be able to parse the JSON string. The questions asked for the values to be replaced.

Comment: Try using your code with `{user: {name: "John Doe"}}`... the output will be `{"user": {"name": '"John" "Doe"'}}` which is invalid JSON. Best filter only the keys.

Comment: @Acidic you are right regarding this scenario. But, as of my requirement i will probably won't encounter such scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/([a-z]+)/ig, "'$1'")
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the simple regex `(\w+):` along with the JavaScript string prototype `replace` function, you're able to replace all instances of the key to be enclosed in single quotes.

Here's an example:

```js
let str = `{
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array
        }
    }
}`;
str = str.replace(/(\w+):/g, (match, key) => {
 return "'"+key+"':";
});
console.log(str);
```

And to convert it to a JavaScript object:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :

```
var obj = {
            props: {
                options: {
                    type: "name"
                }
            }
        };

    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: This would work only if its a object. I had it as string.